# How to ensure data synchronization across threads within a "safe" area (e.g not in a critical section) without locking everything

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, task

We are using a proprietary API that requires synchronization of data at some point.
I've thought about some ways of ensuring data consistency but am eager to get more input on better solutions.

Here is a long running `Task` outlining the API syncing

```
new Task(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        // Here other threads can access any API object (that's fine)

        API.CriticalOperationStart(); // Between start and end no API Object may be used
        API.CriticalOperationEnd();

        // Here other threads can access any API object (that's fine too)
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
```

This is a separate task that actually does some data syncing.

The area between  Start and End is critical. **No** other API call may be done while the API is in this *critical* step.

Here are some non guarded Threads using **distinct** API Objects:

```
// multiple calls to different API objects should not be exclusive
OtherThread1
APIObject1.SetData(42);

OtherThread2
APIObject2.SetData(43);
```

**Constraints**:

No `APIObject` Method is allowed to be called during the API is in the critical section.
Both `SetData` calls are **allowed** to be done simultaneously. They do not interfere with each other, only with the critical section. 
Generally speaking accessing one `APIObject` from multiple threads is **not** thread-safe but accessing multiple `APIObjects` does not interfere with the API except during critical section.
The critical section must never be executed while any `APIObject` Method is used.
Guarding access to one `APIObject` from multiple threads is not required.

---

**The trivial approach**

Use a lock Object and `lock` the critical section and every call to API Objects.

This would effectively work but creates many unnecessary locks because of the fact that then also only one `APIObject` at a time could be accessed too.

---

**Concurrent container of Actions**

Use a single instance of a concurrent container where each modification of an `APIObject` is placed into a thread safe container and is executed in the task above explicitly by traversing the container outside the critical section and calling all actions. (Not a Consumer pattern, as waiting for new entries of the container must not block the task since the critical section must be executed periodically)

This imposes some drawbacks. Closure issues when capturing contexts could be one. Another would be reading from an `APIObject` returns old data as long as the actions in the container are not executed. Even worse if the creation of an `APIObject` is put in the container and subsequent code assumes it has already be created.

---

**Make something up with Wait Handles and atomic increments**

Every `APIObject` access could be guarded with a `ManualResetEvent`. The critical section would wait for the signal to be set by the `APIObjects`, the signal would only be set when all calls to `APIObjects` have finished (some sort of atomic increments/decrement around accessing `APIObjects`).

Sounds like a great way for deadlocks. May lock out the critical section for long periods of time when continuous `APIObject` calls prevent the signal from being ever set.

Does not solve the problem that `APIObjects` may not be accessed during critical section since this construct only guards in the other direction.
Requires additional locking (e.g `Monitor.IsEntered` on the critical section to not lock out simultaneous calls to distinct `APIObjects`).

=> Awful way, making a complex situation even more complex

Comment: It occurred to me that you might abuse a reader/writer lock for this. Every thread would ask for a read lock which would not lock out others also wanting a read lock. For your "critical section" you would then request a write lock. This would lock out everyone else.

Comment: I tend to agree. The only syncing technique I ignored on the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx . D'oh!

Comment: I would wrap up the lock object in a new class though, one that made it clear what behavior you're after. If anyone else, or even you six months from you, comes to read that code they might wonder why you're taking read locks when you're definitely writing inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If copying an `APIObject` is relatively inexpensive (or if it's moderately expensive and you don't sync very often) then you can put the objects in a wrapper that contains a singleton `global_timestamp` and a `local_timestamp`.  When you update an object you first check to see if `global_timestamp == long.MaxValue`: if true, then return a destructively updated object; if `global_timestamp != long.MaxValue` and `global_timestamp == local_timestamp`, then return a destructively updated object.  However if `global_timestamp != long.MaxValue` and `global_timestamp != local_timestamp` then return an updated copy of the object and set `local_timestamp = global_timestamp`.  When you perform a sync, use an `Interlocked` update to set `global_timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary`, and when the sync is complete set `global_timestamp = long.MaxValue`.  This way the rest of the program doesn't have to pause while a sync is performed, and the sync should have consistent data.

```
// APIObject provided to you
public class APIObject {
  private string foo;
  public void setFoo(string _foo) {
    this.foo = _foo;
  }
}

// Global Timestamp, readonly version for wrappers and readwrite version for sync
public class GlobalTimestamp {
  protected long timestamp = long.MaxValue;

  public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
  }
}

public class GlobalTimestampRW extends GlobalTimestamp {
  public void startSync(long _timestamp) {
    long value = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref timestamp, _timestamp, long.MaxValue);
    if(value != long.MaxValue) throw exception; // somebody else called this method already
  }

  public void endSync(long _timestamp) {
    long value = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref timestamp, long.MaxValue, _timestamp);
    if(value != _timestamp) throw exception; // somebody else called this method already
  }
}

// Wrapper
public class APIWrapper {
  private APIObject apiObject;
  private GlobalTimestamp globalTimestamp;
  private long localTimestamp = long.MinValue;

  public APIObject setFoo(string _foo) {
    long tempGlobalTimestamp = globalTimestamp.getTimestamp();
    if(tempGlobalTimestamp == long.MaxValue || tempGlobalTimestamp == localTimestamp) {
      apiObject.setFoo(_foo);
      return apiObject;
    } else {
      apiObject = apiObject.copy();
      apiObject.setFoo(_foo);
      localTimestamp = tempGlobalTimestamp;
      return apiObject;
    }
  }
}

GlobalTimestampRW globalTimestamp;
new Task(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
      long timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary();
      globalTimestamp.startSync(timestamp);
      API.CriticalOperationStart(); // Between start and end no API Object may be used
      API.CriticalOperationEnd();
      globalTimestamp.endSync(timestamp);
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
```